# Why Twitter divs are behaving like button?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, dom

I recently tried to use selenium for learning. When I inspected the Twitter button, I find a div instead of a button.

Why Twitter div is behaving like a button?

Here is the tweet button code.

```
<div dir="auto" class="css-901oao r-1awozwy r-jwli3a r-6koalj r-18u37iz r-16y2uox r-1qd0xha r-a023e6 r-b88u0q r-1777fci r-eljoum r-dnmrzs r-bcqeeo r-q4m81j r-qvutc0"><span class="css-901oao css-16my406 css-bfa6kz r-1qd0xha r-ad9z0x r-bcqeeo r-qvutc0"><span class="css-901oao css-16my406 r-1qd0xha r-ad9z0x r-bcqeeo r-qvutc0">Tweet</span></span></div>
```

Is it because Twitter is using react(jsx) that why div are behaving like button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are substituting a combination of:

- JavaScript
- CSS
- ARIA

… in order to make a div which acts like a button.

This isn't generally recommended as it requires a *lot* of work in order to ensure that the behaviour is consistent with how real buttons work across a variety of clients (including those which make use of screen readers or braille displays).

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to use button for clicking and submitting forms. You can attach event listeners to any node in the DOM using JS and design div like a button. That's why div is behaving like a button because they have registered onclick event on a div instead of putting a button there.

Comment: But there is no oneclick in the div

Comment: you cannot see events registered in dom, it is in js file.